# Радио кнопки с собственным оформлением

Tags: html, css

Требуется создать группу радио кнопок, но это будут не обычные input, они будут с использованием div(собственное оформление).

```
 1.Требуется очень простенькая реализация
 2.Две радио кнопки обьеденены в одну группу, тоесть нажал на одну другая если активирована должна деактивироватся, нажал другую тажа история.
 3.На css.
```

Comment: Что означает «будут выгледить как div»? Сделать 2 div блока с таким же свойствами как группа радио кнопок? Или Радиокнопки должны быть блочным элементом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upd:
Понял в чём задача. Добавил решение. Стили сделал, а дальше можете кастомизировать под свои нужны

```css
input.custom{
  display:none;
}
input[type=radio].custom:checked + label{
  font-size:20px;
}
input[type=radio].custom + label:before{
  content:"-";
  padding-right:10px;
}
input[type=radio].custom:checked + label:before{
  content:"+";
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="test" class="custom" value="раз" id="one"><label for="one">Раз</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="test" class="custom" value="два" id="two"><label for="two">Два</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Галочки вижу работают, но если отключить этот самый js из браузера не будут работать именно галочки, пока не подходит. Мой сайт без js на обычном css + html5

Comment: И считывание у меня проходит через form, тоесть требуется использование <input>

Comment: Прошу прощения, не понял задачу. Обновил решение

Comment: Да, вижу обновление.

Comment: О, спасибо вижу решение и рабочий вариант, как только разберусь отмечу.